# Pod node-exporter does not have a host assigned in prometheus on azure kubernetes service

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, azure-aks, prometheus-node-exporter

I have upgraded the aks version from 1.14.8 to 1.15.7 and on doing that the I got some error on prometheus node-exporter. There are 2 pods and it says "0/2 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match node selector, 2 node(s) didn't have free ports for the requested pod ports."
[image]

Any idea on resolving this issue would be very helpful.

Comment: Please share more information about your environment. Send output from `kubectl describe nodes` and `kubectl describe statefulsets`.